# Create validation to input alphanumeric and with specified symbols for field type password in user module

Tags: users

In the user module for field type password input I want to avoid hazardous characters input so i added #required and '#element_validate. But as i am new to drupal i dont know how to processed and also i am not sure if i am in right direction or not . Please help me

```
if (!$register) {
  $form['account']['pass'] = array(
  '#type' => 'password_confirm',
  '#size' => 25,
  '#description' => t('To change the current user password, enter the new password in both fields.'),
   //The below two lines are added by naveena. 
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#element_validate' => array('user_pass_element_validate'),  

);

function user_pass_element_validate($element, &$form_state, $form) {
  if (!empty($element['#value'])) {
    form_error($element, t(''));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`user_validate_current_pass()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_validate_current_pass/7).